# Create Table in Azure SQL Server for mobile services (.net Backend)

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am creating table in Azure SQL Server using mobile services webservice (.net backend). But table is not created in SQL Server.

My questions are:

1. Can I create table manually in Azure SQL Server?
2. If I can create table then there will any possibility of error?
3. Is there any possibility to find out why table is not creating?

Please provide your suggestions how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the .NET backend, you are operating in Entity Framework for table management.  You will likely need to do an [EF Migration](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework6/introduction.aspx) to create the table - there is no dynamic schema / table maintenance.  It's best to learn Entity Framework and go from there.

Specifically:

1) Yes, you can create the table manually in the SQL Management Studio.

2) You will need to define the appropriate table within your .NET backend as well.  The schema must match what is expected.  You can't just take any old table and expect it to work

3) You can turn on logging in the Entity Framework and see the underlying SQL statements and errors being returned by SQL Server.  However, your problem is likely to be because Entity Framework hasn't run a migration.

Comment: when are the tables created? after publishing or first http request to specific controller?

Comment: It depends on whether you are talking Node or .NET - since this is a .NET questions, it's done when the controller is first instantiated, which is on the first HTTP request routed to the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer.

Table has created by using mobile services.

Actually table has been created by using mobile services but it was not displaying in sql server. To display table in sqlserver i have to do action (like insert,update data) in atleast one table. then all table display.

Comment: That's because the database is created lazily by Entity Framework, and then the database creation code kicks in. To change this, you should use Entity Framework migrations that you apply manually. The Entity Framework documentation explains these options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. If you use Mobile Services, go to the dashboard and Configure - here, you will see the database server link. Go to that, and get the connection string. Then, you can connect with something like, for example, SQL Server Management Studio 2014 (i would recommend to do that to avoid any support inconsistencies) and do what you want with the database (with some limitations, however). You may do that using Visual Studio as well.

If you use Mobile Apps, go to the Mobile App dashboard, then Data Connections - here, you will see the hidden connection string that you can use for connecting the same way as described above.